# Load content with timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

I have a page with some content. When it opens, I want to display only the first div, and load all the others by timer, after 5 seconds. How to do that?

Code exampe:

```
    <div id="first_loaded"></div>
    <div id="loaded_after_5sec"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by loading a DIV? How do you retrieve specific content? Couldn't you improve your question? If by load you mean show then forget my comment...

Comment: how do you load those div?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this using CSS, JavaScript and/or jQuery. What have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Use `classes` instead of `id`s since you have more than one `div`.

**CSS**

```
.loaded_after_5sec { display:none; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="first_loaded">First</div>
<div class="loaded_after_5sec">Second</div>
<div class="loaded_after_5sec">Third</div>
```

**JS**

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $('.loaded_after_5sec').show();
}, 5000);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/GTxd8/)

Comment: And if you want to have each div loading 5 seconds after the next, you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/GTxd8/2/ although I'm sure there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT Thanks to Andy!**
Change your ID tags to Class tags.

This will hide the object before it will be shown with a timer.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".loaded_after_5sec").hide();
    });

setTimeout(function(){
    $(".loaded_after_5sec").show();
}, 5000);
```

How ever I'd prefer the following for hiding the object:

**CSS**

```
.loaded_after_5sec {display:none;}
```

Comment: This will only target _one_ div with id = loaded_after_5sec.

Comment: Well to be honest thats really basic html/js which you should know before making these functions...

Comment: But the OP wants to load more than one div after 5 seconds. This answer won't do that.

Answer (score 1):

## <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/b3dwY/)</kbd>

You need to use [`.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout), `.setInterval` will execute *every* 5 seconds, which is not what you want.

JS code-

```
// On document ready, hide the div
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loaded_after_5sec").hide();
});

// After 5 seconds (5000 ms), show it
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#loaded_after_5sec").show();
}, 5000);
```

As @Andy points out in the comments, use `.loaded_after_5sec` instead of `#loaded_after_5sec`

Comment: This will only target _one_ div with id = loaded_after_5sec.

Comment: @Andy Yep! You are right. The OP had given the ids, so I went on with ids only. Your answer seems better. +1.